# If $ax + by = c$ has an integer solution for $x,y$ then it has infinitely many

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

> Let $a, b, c$ be integers. Show that if the equation $ax + by = c$ has a solution where $x$ and $y$ are integers, then it has infinitely many such solutions.

How would I go about showing this?

I can start off by doing the following:

$$by = c - ax$$

$$y = \frac{c - ax}b$$

Comment: In fact, you can actually say much more. The equation $ax+by=c$ has solutions $(x,y)\in\Bbb Z^2$ iff $\gcd(a,b)\mid c$ and the solutions (when they exist) are the [Bezout coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) for $a,b$ (scaled by $c/\gcd(a,b)$)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If $(x,y)$ satisfy the equation, check that $(x-b, y+a)$ is also a solution

$$a(x-b)+b(y+a) = c$$

Can you see why does it imply there are infinitely many solutions?

Answer (score 8):

If $x,y$ is a solution then
$$x+nb, y-na$$ is also a solution for all $n$.

Answer (score 2):

Given your equation we want to find if there are any integer solutions to :

$$ a(x+\epsilon)+b(y-\omega)=c $$

for $\epsilon$ and $\omega$ both integers.  The choice of signs is for convenience.

Which gets us :

$$a\epsilon - b\omega + (ax+by) = c$$

So :

$$a\epsilon = b\omega$$

Now it's pretty easy to see that this works for any $\epsilon$ such that :

$$\epsilon = n\,\frac{b}{gcd(a,b)}$$

$$\omega = \frac a b n \frac{b}{gcd(a,b)} = n\frac{a}{gcd(a,b)}$$

for any $n$ an integer

Which means there are an infinite number of such combinations.